# How to use a variable as a pattern along with the other patterns in preg_match() function?

Tags: php, regex, web-crawler, preg-match, preg-match-all

Actually I'm writing a web crawler for my mini project.
I want to crawl only those web pages that belong to the input website only. I want my web crawler not to crawl to other websites other than the input given for now.

This is what I'm doing:

    `$url = $_POST["url"];
    $web = @file_get_contents($url);
    preg_match_all("/<a\s.*href=\"(.*)\"/U", $web, $matches);`

What I want to do is:

    `$url = $_POST["url"];
    $web = @file_get_contents($url);
    preg_match_all("/<a\s.*href=\"(.*$url.*)\"/U", $web, $matches);`

for example: 
Input: https://www.google.com/
then the regular expression should be :
    `preg_match("/.*google.com.*/U", xyz, xyz);`
Any other suggestions will be helpful, thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Naruto kun. Asking a clear question will make it easier to help you. please read this article to make sure that you get a good answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Change your delimiters to something that is not in any of your URLs?

```
preg_match_all("#<a\s.*href=\"(.*$url.*)\"#U", $web, $matches);
```

*edit*

Probably better to escape the $url with [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)

Comment: Pound signs are found in URLs, but maybe this helps anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, here's the solution.
If you want to use a variable along with the regular expression.

```
preg_match("/regular_expression".($my_variable)."regular_expression/U", $source, $matches);
```

Comment: What if you have a ``/``  in your `$my_variable`?

Comment: Basically in my case $my_variable is a web page's name, so there is no chance of having a " / " in the variable. And if you want to include a " / "  then put a " \ " before the " / ". For example: if I want to write a regexp for a link then I would write ..     `preg_match( "/https:\/\/.*\.com/U", xyz, xyz);`

Comment: If you use a variable, you need to `preg_quote` it. With additional char that is your regexdelimiter.

Answer (score 0):

The real solution is to use a [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) with the actual regex delimiter and append the part to the regex literal parts with the dot syntax:

```
preg_match_all("/<a\s.*href=\"(.*" . preg_quote($url, "/") . ".*)\"/U", $web, $matches);
                                   ^ ^^^^^^^^^^       ^^^  ^
```

The dots are like `+` in some other languages used for string concatenation, and `preg_quote` will make sure all special regex metacharacters in the variable string are properly escaped.